# How to extract value in JSON by using Regular Expression

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I am new to regular expression and not able to find the solution of my problem. I have one JSON which my service is returning in response

```
"{\"Version\":14,\"Collections\":[{\"Id\":\"**************\",{\"Id\":\"**************\"\
"Solutions\":[{\"Id\":\"**************\"",{\"Id\":\"**************\"
```

which consists of multiple collections and multiple solutions having multiple ids in both and I want to extract the all id's related to collections only not solution id and when want to extract the solutions id's only not collection id's.

I am using `----- "Id.":."(.+?).",."---` but it is giving both id's i.e. collections and solutions.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse JSON. JSON is not regular

Answer (score 1):

Please post the full response data as partial one doesn't tell the full story.

[JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) therefore trying to parse it using regular expressions is not the best idea, JMeter provides [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) which are way more handy and powerful.